# find and sketch the distribution and density function of the random variable y = g(x). where x ~ N(0,c^2), and g(x) = x^2,

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

find and sketch the distribution and density function of the random variable y = g(x). If the random variable x ~ N(0,c^2), and g(x) = x^2,

any help on this would be great.

Comment: What have you tried? Are there any properties of the distribution you can guess at?